# How to enroll in contest?

Tags: support, contest

I see the contest going on right now on Writing Meta about the tags and Questions.
 I would like myself to include my question in this contest, but I didn't find a way to submit my entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start here:
[Contest: ask questions, earn badges, win prizes! (final week)](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/contest-ask-questions-earn-badges-win-prizes-final-week?cb=1)

The contest rules are in the form of a question on Meta.

The submissions are in the form of an answer.

Go to the bottom of the answer and click on "edit."  Add your name, then put relevant tags, and question link on a new line.  Start a new line for each qualifying question.  Be sure to read the rules carefully and ask if you have any more questions about it.

Comment: I'm not allowed to edit that answer to enroll

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi You can leave a comment under that "answer" in that case. Someone with enough reputation can edit that in for you when they come across your comment. You need 1000 reputation to edit posts. On Main you can also suggest an edit with less than 1k rep, but on Meta there is no edit suggestion. So just leave a comment with a link to your question(s) and ask if someone can edit that in.

Comment: @Secespitus Please add https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/43694/do-i-need-to-convey-a-moral-for-each-of-my-blog-posts and help to enroll me.

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi Done. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: @Secespitus the rep requirement is lower for community wiki -- 100, which Prasad has now reached.  Prasad, sorry about the inconvenience; the SE platform has some limitations (e.g. to fight spam), which can be frustrating for new contributors.  Sorry about that!